# hook_schema is not creating database table

Tags: 7, database

The following function is contained in process_login.install as part of a custom module called process_login. The module works if I manually created the database table, but naturally I would like the table created automatically on install.

The function itself does not generate a schema error on installing the module. But neither does it create the database table process_login_register in the Drupal 7 MySQL database.

There are no other errors I can see, or problems reported by Site Report.

I have removed it completely and reinstalled numerous times. I have searched the web extensively, and consulted two books I have on Drupal development. I can't see anything wrong with this function (listed below).

NOTE: I have also tried defining 'id' as serial but get the same result (i.e. no table created).

I have run out of ideas. Does anybody know why this function isn't working?

```
function process_login_schema(){
  $schema['process_login_register'] = array(
        'description' => 'Register a specific computer with the system.',
        'fields' => array(
                'id' => array(
                    'description' => 'Primary identifier.',
                    'type' => 'int',
                    'unsigned' => TRUE,
                    'size' => 'normal',
                    'not null' => TRUE,
                    'default' => 0,
                ),
                'ip' => array(
                        'description' => "The user's IP address at registration.",
                        'type' => 'varchar',
                        'length' => 32,
                        'not null' => TRUE,
                        'default' => '',
                ),
                'user_agent' => array(
                        'description' => "The user's browser user agent string at registration.",
                        'type' => 'varchar',
                        'length' => 255,
                        'not null' => TRUE,
                        'default' => '',
                ),
        ),
        'primary key' => array('id'),
  );
  return $schema;
}
```

Comment: What Drupal version are you using?

Comment: Have you actually uninstalled and reinstalled (not just disabled and re-enabled) the module since writing the function?

Comment: Drupal 6 requires to call drupal_install_schema() in hook_install. In Drupal 7 it is recommended not to call it explicitly.

Comment: Answers to above: Drupal 7. Yes. I'm using Drupal 7 so not calling drupal_install_schema().

Comment: I've also had something of a break-through and will post my solution soon. I'm not yet exactly sure why it just worked and am trying to find out. Current theories: phpMyAdmin had some sort of lock in place (very unlikely), or perhaps I had to actually use the uninstall tab rather than merely disabling and then deleting ~/all/modules/custom/process_login/

Comment: Ok, I think using the "Uninstall" tab is required and not just physically removing the module directory. I think Drupal 7 thought the table still existed even though it didn't. A more experienced member can probably confirm this for the benefit of all.

Comment: The system won't let me answer my own question, so here's what I've found: I am now certain it's essential to use the Uninstall tab to uninstall the module. Only after uninstalling via the uninstall tab can the module's folder be removed.

My working theory is that the uninstall tab informs Drupal that a table it thinks exists does in fact no longer exist. Merely confirming the non-existence of the table in the database is not enough.

NOTE: If the module doesn't show in the list after clicking the Uninstall tab, it is necessary to reenable the module and then uncheck it again.

Comment: @user8109 Enabling/disabling and installing/uninstalling are two completely different things in modules. Enabling a module (checking it in the modules page and pressing 'Submit') will only enable a module, and invoke `hook_enable()`. Installing a module can only be done after it's been uninstalled (using the uninstall tab or devel/reinstall), after which all tables created by the module are deleted. When you then install the module, `hook_install()` is run as you'd expect

Comment: Thanks :) I was facing same issue ... your answer helped

Answer (score 22):

Use `drush dre -y [module]` which disables, uninstalls and then re-enables the module. The `-y` flag makes it even faster, avoiding you have to press *y* and enter three times.

Answer (score 15):

Only if you uninstall a module, and subsequently re-install it, the database tables it uses and declares with `hook_schema()` are re-created.

To uninstall a module, you need to:

- Uncheck the checkbox shown for the module

  [image: screenshot]
- Click on *Save configuration*

  [image: screenshot]
- Click on the :Uninstall_ tab
- Click on the check box to the left of the module name
- Click on the *Uninstall* button

  [image: screenshot]
- On the next page, confirm you want to uninstall that module by clicking on the *Uninstall* button

  [image: screenshot]

As alternative, if you have installed Drush, you can use the following commands.

```bsh
drush pm-disable $module
drush pm-install $module
drush en $module
```

Replace `$module` with the short name of the module, between apices, and without the .module extension.

What you have done is disabling the module, and then re-enabling it. Even if you deleted the directory containing the module, for Drupal what you have done is just disabling, and then re-enabling it.

Comment: Is it possible to do this using drupal_install_schema and drupal_uninstall_schema .... https://www.drupal.org/node/876250