# hook_scheme doesn't work

Tags: 7, hooks, installation, database

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [hook_schema is not creating database table](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/34394/hook-schema-is-not-creating-database-table)

I am developing a module in Drupal 7. It is called scorm. I created scorm.install file, where I wanted to create the necessary tables, when the module is being installed. For testing I used book module: I installed it and 'book' table was created.

So I took the code from book.install, renamed all the functions prefixes from 'book_' to 'scorm_' and tried to install my module. I added this code to scorm_schema function:

```
function scorm_schema() {
    print 123;exit;
```

And 123 was printed when installing. So I removed this test code, being sure, that the hook is called.

But the book table was not created! How can I debug and find out the cause of problem?

Comment: Take a look here http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_schema/7. + You should care about the types.

Comment: Just in case: The tables are create after you uninstalled the module and install it again. Switching it on/off is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

`hook_schema()` should return an array that defines a database schema.

Comment: I return it. So, this is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Book table was created after I disabled and uninstalled the module. Then enabled it again, using this set of commands:

```
drush pm-disable 'scorm'
drush pm-install 'scorm'
drush en 'scorm'
```