# Why table creation on module install doesn't work?

Tags: 7, installation

I need to create custom table for module, but after module install table is not created.

module.install file:

```
function bip_content_migration_schema() {

    $schema['bip_migrate'] = array(

            'description' => 'Storing content migration info from Joomla.',
            'fields' => array(

                    'id' => array(
                            'description' => 'id',
                            'type' => 'serial',
                    ),
                    'content_type' => array(
                            'description' => 'content type',
                            'type' => 'varchar',
                            'not null' => TRUE,
                            'length' => 255,
                    ),
                    'imported_count' => array(
                            'description' => 'imported count',
                            'type' => 'int',
                            'not null' => TRUE,
                            'default' => 0,
                    ),
                    'to_import_count' => array(
                            'description' => 'to import count',
                            'type' => 'int',
                            'not_null' => TRUE,
                    ),
                    'is_imported' => array(
                            'description' => 'is imported',
                            'type' => 'int',
                            'default' => 0,
                    ),
            ),
            'primary key' => array('id'),
            'indexes' => array(
                    'id' => array('id'),
            ),
    );
    return $schema;

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

I added functions to my .install file (thought that I can ommit theme)

```
function bip_content_migration_install() {
    drupal_install_schema('bip_content_migration');
}

function bip_content_migration_uninstall() {
    drupal_uninstall_schema('bip_content_migration');
}
```

But again table is not created.

Comment: Have you after disabling your module, uninstalled it as well?  I am thinking D7 won't look at this until you actually do the uninstall part that goes and deletes the DB tables.  Then if you re-enable it, it will call the schema and install your table.  Eg, `The tables declared by this hook will be automatically created when the module is first enabled, and removed when the module is uninstalled. This happens before hook_install() is invoked, and after hook_uninstall() is invoked, respectively.` from http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_schema/7

Comment: as @Jimajamma said, try Devel's re-install feature to re-installing your module and force drupal to call hook_schema()

Comment: How did you solve this issue ? what was the problem here

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Drupal 7, it is not necessary to call `drupal_install_schema()`, or `drupal_uninstall_schema()`; that is automatically done from Drupal. It is enough to implement `hook_schema()`, and the database table is created. There are many modules for Drupal 7 implementing that hook, and their database tables are created.

I can think of two possible causes for the database table not being created:

- The short name of the module is not bip_content_migration
- You added the `hook_schema()` implementation on an already installed module

If you installed the module, disabled it, changed the code, and re-enabled it, the database table would not be created. Disabling a module is different from uninstalling it. Uninstalling is done when a module is disabled, and then uninstalled from the "Uninstall" tab in admin/modules.

[image: screenshot]

I didn't considered the following two cases, as Drupal should have given you some errors:

- The schema is not correct
- Drupal is not able to connect to the database, while installing the module.

If there are more databases, be sure you are looking at the right database.

Comment: but here it says https://www.drupal.org/node/876250 we need to use hook_install and hook_uninstall ...can you please explain do we need to use hook_install and hook_uninstall or not ?

Comment: The documentation has been copied from Drupal 6 documentation, it seems. That is what you had to do in Drupal 6.

Comment: IN D7? do we not need it ?

Comment: You just need to implement `hook_schema()`, in Drupal 7.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old but anyway. If you are trying to see changes on **re-enable** the module, first, you need to disable and uninstall the module. Use

> drush dre [module]

More info here
[hook_schema is not creating database table](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/34394/hook-schema-is-not-creating-database-table)

Answer (score 0):

Disable the module. Search your module name in 'system' table name column(drupal database) and delete that particular column. Try again by enabling the module. your table will be created.